# How to move values from one column to another based on a condition in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with three columns: Col1, Col2, Col3. The data in Col1 can be either a number or text. If the value in Col1 is greater than 1000000, I want to move that value to the next column (Col2). Here is an example of the data:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(1100000, 5320133, "Teste", "Cor13", "Fell505", 2732154),
                 Col2 = c(0, 0, 1100000, 5320133, 2732154, 0),
                 Col3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I want the data to be transformed to look like this:

```
df_new <- data.frame(Col1 = c("", "", "Teste", "Cor13", "Fell505", ""),
                     Col2 = c(1100000, 5320133, 1100000, 5320133, 2732154, 2732154),
                     Col3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(test=as.numeric(Col1),
              test2=as.numeric(Col2),
              Col2=ifelse(test>1000000,Col1,Col2),
              Col2=ifelse(is.na(Col2)==T,test2,Col2)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(Col1,Col2,Col3 )%>% 
  mutate(test=as.numeric(Col1),
         Col1=ifelse(is.na(test)==T,Col1,"")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(!test)
```

The use of multiple data types makes this difficult and this isn't super clean but I'll leave that part up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_extract` to get the numbers. Note that this replaces a value in *Col2*. Use `val + Col2` if you want to make sure the data is preserved.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(val = as.numeric(str_extract(Col1, "\\d+")), 
  Col2 = if_else(val > 1000000 & !is.na(val), val, Col2), 
  val = NULL)
     Col1    Col2 Col3
1 1100000 1100000    0
2 5320133 5320133    0
3   Teste 1100000    0
4   Cor13 5320133    0
5 Fell505 2732154    0
6 2732154 2732154    0
```

If you want to use **base R**

```
val <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", df$Col1))

df$Col2 <- ifelse(val > 1000000 & !is.na(val), val, df$Col2)

df
     Col1    Col2 Col3
1 1100000 1100000    0
2 5320133 5320133    0
3   Teste 1100000    0
4   Cor13 5320133    0
5 Fell505 2732154    0
6 2732154 2732154    0
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach using a loop, which is not very R-like, might be:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  # for checks coerce entries to numeric 
  if(as.numeric(df$Col1[i]) > 1e6 & !is.na(as.numeric(df$Col1[i]))) {

    # duplicate entry from Col1 to Col2
    df$Col2[i] <- df$Col1[i]

    # replace respective entry in Col1
    df$Col1[i] <- " " # or NA, NaN 

    } 

}
```

Gives

```
> df
     Col1    Col2 Col3
1         1100000    0
2         5320133    0
3   Teste 1100000    0
4   Cor13 5320133    0
5 Fell505 2732154    0
6         2732154    0
```

We can ignore the warning messages as they are more or less intended by the `is.na()`-trick to overcome the uncommon data format. Alternatively, you might wrap the loop into `suppressWarnings()`.